# Decompile, recover app from .apk using original key-hash?

Tags: android, hash, apk, decompiling

Sadly I have erased the source folder of my app. All I have now is the latest apk I have exported and the key hash I have used to upload my app to the play store.

I saw there are several ways to decompile, but none of them mentions the key hash, can this help in the recovering process?

Thankx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use decompileandroid.com or javadecompilers.com/apk you will get everything of your app.
Key Hash is of no use in decomompiling process.